# Getting the actual datatype of a value in an XML node- C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, types

I'm reading an XML file, in which a node element is having a float value.

I'm using XmlTextReader.ValueType to get the type of each value, but even for elements having float value(e.g. price), it is returning the data type as System.String.

How to get the actual data type of each element? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If your XML file doesn't have an XSD attached, XmlTextReader can't know which type to expect. In this case it returns the default value "string".

Comment: +1. Exactly. Look at the XML, Ruchir - you think there is now an articficial intelligence running trying to figure out whether the text is a number or not? Bad new - it is not. An XSD - schema - defines that. WIthout the definition everything IS a text becauswe a XML File is a TEXT file.